# How to hide remote branches without deleting them from remote

Tags: git

How to hide remote branches without deleting it?
I often display the whole tree of commits by

```
 git log --graph --oneline --all
```

This currently display all the remote branches...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the `--exclude` option:

```
git log --graph --oneline --exclude=refs/remotes/* --all
```

Note that the `--exclude` option must appear *before* the `--all` option. See the [`git log`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log) documentation for further information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
git log --graph --oneline --tags --branches
```

Add `HEAD` if you are on a detached head.

The options `--tags`, `--branches`, `--remotes` are quite versatile when combined with `--exclude`. For example, I have many branches named `wip/foo`, `wip/bar` that contain work in progress. I commonly use

```
gitk --exclude=wip/* --branches ^master
```

to see all branches that are not yet merged into `master`, but without cluttering the list with work-in-progress.